# Blazor Server AD B2C Get Unique User Id

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get the unique user identification out of Azure AD B2C. I think there must be a unique user identification id, not the one who identifies some actual login states etc. I am looking for the user id which is unique linked with the user mail address in AD B2C and alwasy unique and same.

I am using following code to get the email, which works:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

private ClaimsPrincipal AuthenticationStateUser { get; set; }
private ClaimsPrincipal AuthenticationStateProviderUser { get; set; }

private string email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

private async Task OnAuthorized()
{
    AuthenticationState authenticationState;

    authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
    this.AuthenticationStateUser = authenticationState.User;

    authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    this.AuthenticationStateProviderUser = authenticationState.User;
    foreach (var claim in this.AuthenticationStateProviderUser.Claims)
    {
        if (claim.Type == "emails")
        {
            email = claim.Value.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("\"", "");
        }
    }   
}
```

Any solution on how I become additionally to to user email the unique user identification id?

Thank's!

Comment: Additional use case info: for example with that unique user id, I need to save custom data on a server and retrieve them when the  user is again logged in. This is not about a real scenario, but shows some possible rough pathes.

Answer (score 0):

The unique field for a user is "[objectId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes)".

This is the field that is presented as "sub" in the JWT after authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes seems this objectId is what I am looking for. Do you can provide some example snippet, on how to get that objectId out of the AuthenticationStateProviderUser ?

Comment: This utility displays it as "id" - https://github.com/rbrayb/B2CGraphClient-UserManagement-MSAL